# Get total of rows with SUM GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to get the total of subtotal that I get from a `SUM` and `GROUP BY` query.

Here is my query so far:

```
  SELECT SUM(opportunite_montant_ht)*(stade_pourcentage/100) 
      As subtotal
    FROM opportunite O 
    JOIN opportunite_stade OS 
      ON O.opportunite_stade=OS.stade_id
GROUP BY stade_id
```

And the result:

```
subtotal

35100.0000

330.0000
```

Now how can I get only the total of these subtotals with my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `WITH ROLLUP` to get subtotal for each stade_id and grand total:

```
SELECT stade_id, SUM(opportunite_montant_ht * stade_pourcentage/100) as subtotal
FROM opportunite O 
JOIN opportunite_stade OS
  ON O.opportunite_stade=OS.stade_id
GROUP BY stade_id WITH ROLLUP;
```

Output will be like:

```
+----------+------------+
| stade_id |  subtotal  |
+----------+------------+
| 1        | 35100.0000 |
| 2        |   330.0000 |
| NULL     | 35430.0000 |
+----------+------------+
```

## EDIT:

> Indeed this works, though I was trying to get only the total, and not all the subtotals

Then use the simplest solution possible - remove `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT SUM(opportunite_montant_ht*stade_pourcentage/100) AS total
FROM opportunite O JOIN opportunite_stade OS ON O.opportunite_stade=OS.stade_id
```

Comment: Indeed this works, though I was trying to get only the total, and not all the subtotals. But thanks :)

Comment: @marcvander Then you don't need to change your query. Just remove `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Indeed it's that simple! I don't know why I was willing to use GROUP BY. Marked solved with this answer

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
select sum(subtotal) from (SELECT SUM(opportunite_montant_ht)*(stade_pourcentage/100) as subtotal
FROM opportunite O JOIN opportunite_stade OS ON O.opportunite_stade=OS.stade_id
GROUP BY stade_id) as query
```

Comment: With this solution I had the error #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias. So I just needed to add a AS at the end, and it works. Thanks !

Comment: So it works but I marked @Lukasz solution as the answer since it is the simpliest

Answer (score 0):

Use an additional `SUM`.

```
SELECT SUM(SUM(opportunite_montant_ht)*(stade_pourcentage/100)) AS subtotal
FROM opportunite O 
JOIN opportunite_stade OS ON O.opportunite_stade= OS.stade_id
GROUP BY stade_id
```

OR:

```
SELECT SUM(SELECT SUM(opportunite_montant_ht)*(stade_pourcentage/100) as subtotal
FROM opportunite O JOIN opportunite_stade OS ON O.opportunite_stade=OS.stade_id
GROUP BY stade_id)
FROM dual
```